# In a Bruhat-Tits building, $N$ is the stabilizer of the standard apartment

Tags: affine-geometry, coxeter-groups, tits-system, bruhat-tits-theory

Let $(G,B,N,S)$ be a Tits system.  Assume the system is saturated, which is to say that if we define

$$H = \bigcap\limits_{n \in N} nBn^{-1}$$

then $H \subseteq N$.  To an affine root system whose Weyl group $(W,S)$ is isomorphic to that of the Tits system, we can associate a Bruhat-Tits building with a standard apartment.  The claim that $N$ is the stabilizer of the standard apartment is equivalent to the following statement which I can trying to  understand the proof of:

> Let $g \in G$, and suppose for every $n \in N$, there exists $n' \in N$ such that $gnBn^{-1}g^{-1} = n'Bn'^{-1}$.  Then $g \in N$.

Taking $n = 1$, and using the fact that parabolic subgroups are self-normalizing, we see that there exists $n'' \in N, b \in B$ such that $g = n''b$.  Again using the self-normalizing property, we have that for every $n \in N$, there exists an $n' \in N$ such that $bn \in n''^{-1}n'B$.

Then I get lost.  The next claim is that $n \in n''^{-1}n'H$, and then that $b \in nBn^{-1}$ for every $n \in N$.  I don't understand why either of these claims are true.

The reference is from Bruhat-Tits article I, (2.2.5).

[image]

Comment: I believe that “$n \in n’’^{-1}n’H$” should read “$n \in n’’^{-1}n’B$” (in B-T).

Comment: I see, since $n \in b^{-1}n''^{-1}n'B$, the double cosets $BnB$ and $Bn''^{-1}n'B$ are equal, so $n$ and $n''^{-1}n'$ are congruent modulo $B \cap N$, hence $n \in n''^{-1}n'B$.